# Varistors set to ground or case by isolated ground/case

Tags: ground, emc, isolation, cases, varistor

I have a isolated ground from the case in my device. The Supply Voltage is +24VDC with Ground and separated CASE, so no safety issues. 
On any signals coming from the case (Plugs) I put varistors, but should I put them to the Ground (Electronic) or to the case for EMC?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the circuit is already isolated then connect the varistors to the local electronic ground. The varistors should be rated 50% higher voltage than the highest signal voltage. If grounding to earth was needed for your AC power, that would normally be done at your circuit-breaker panel.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Could you explain to me why you would connect it to the local electronic ground?

Comment: Varistors work best when their leads are short. If it is protecting signals, then the best and shortest return path is to signal ground. If your protecting the AC power line, those varistors would connect from the AC power to AC (earth) ground.

Comment: Thanks! I have 24V DC only. My new concept is to take TVS-Diodes (less resistive than varistors) to the inputs of the connectors to my GND (near the plugs) and to connect the GND and the chassis with 50V varistor’s. What do you think of that?

Comment: @user289280. TVS diodes are faster responding and have a sharper cutoff than varistors. They also have much less capacitance, which could affect signal quality. I am glad you know about TVS diodes.